# struts 2 reset, datepicker is not working with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using struts 2 with jquery plugin for date picker. 
When I  mouse over the date picker, it is showing "..." (3 dots) by default. When I tried to change it , it had no effect. I set display format as dd/mm/yy, but when I press the reset button, it is showing some other format. Here is the code snippet:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<sj:datepicker id="fromDate" name="searchBean.fromDate" maxDate="new Date()"  
changeMonth="true" changeYear="true"  buttonImageOnly="true"   
onCompleteTopics="onDpClose" cssStyle="width: 134px; margin-right:5px;"    
 displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" disabled="true" />
```

I'm confused why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i came to know that, Basically it is a Bug in the datepicker tooltip.

Comment: So What did you do Then .. ? Have to leave like that Or any other Ways to deal that ?

Comment: date format issue got fixed by giving MM instead of mm.. and i left with tooltip issue.. in later versions of datepicker it might be fixed..